# elastic search return data if doc count is zero also

Tags: elasticsearch

```
 let peopleCount = {
  size: 0,
  aggs: {
     //'min_doc_count': 0,
    group_by_day: {
     // min_doc_count: 0,
      date_histogram: {
        field: 'timestamp',
        interval: '1d',
        time_zone: '+11:00',
        //format : 'yyyy-MM-dd'
      },
      aggs: {
      //  min_doc_count: 0,
        Location: {
          filter: {
           
            match: {
              'data.name': 'Entrance',
            
            },
          
          },
          aggs: {
            // min_doc_count: '0',
            cou: {
              sum: {
                field: 'data.north',
              },
             
            },
            
          },
        },
      },
    },
   
  },
  query: {
    bool: {
      
      must: [
        {
          // range: { timestamp: { gte: startDate, lte: endDate } }
          range: { timestamp: { gte: '2020-03-20', lte: '2020-03-28' } },
        },
        {
          term: {
            account: accountId,
          },
        },
        {
          term: {
            'device._id': deviceId,
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  },
};
```

this is my query for elastic search but i want to return all data if the doc counit is zero also. i try to add min-doc-count but it gives me this error.

```
parsing_exception] Aggregation definition for [min_doc_count starts with a [VALUE_NUMBER], expected a [START_OBJECT]., with { line=1 & col=35 }
```

can you guys tell where should i add min doc count in this query or if there is any other option to fullfill my requirement

Answer (score 0):

The cause of your error is the fact that `min_doc_count` was treated as a standalone aggregation rather that an agg setting/parameter. On top of that, `min_doc_count` is only used in `terms`, `histogram` aggs and others, not in numeric metrics like `sum`. What's used instead is the [`missing`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch///reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-sum-aggregation.html#_missing_value_12) parameter. But when you set it to `0`, it'd have the same effect as not setting at all.

It's not immediately clear from your question what you mean by `wanting to return all data where the doc count is 0`. But I suspect you want to aggregate irregardless of your queries. In that case you essentially have 2 options:

1. Use [`filter`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html%C3%A4) aggs to separately aggregate values that fulfil one or the other query.
2. Or use the [`global`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-global-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-global-aggregation) agg which disregards the top-level query and enables you to aggregate outside of its scope (globally).

The two can of course be combined.